# Swift: change tableview height on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a VC as shown in the image[image]

It has a **UICollectionView** on top, and a **UITableView** at the bottom.
CollectionView has 1:3 of the screen and TableView has 2:3 of the screen(set using equalHeight constraint).

I want to **change the height** of the **UICollectionView** when the **tableView is scrolled**.

When the **tableView** is **scrolled up**,I want to change the multiplier of equalHeights constraint to like 1:5 and 4:5 of collectionView and tableView respectively.This will ensure that **height of tableView increases** and **collectionView decreases**

When the **tableView** is **scrolled down**, the multiplier of equalHeights constraint should **reset to default**.

I've tried adding swipe and pan gestures to tableView, but they are unrecognised.

How to achieve this functionality?

P.S: Would love to achieve this functionality by using a pan gesture, so that dragging up and down changes the heights progressively.

This is the view hierarchy[image]

**EDIT/UPDATE**

This is the code that I'm using.

```
class MyConstant {
    var height:CGFloat = 10
}

let myConstant = MyConstant()
```

MainScreenVC

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myConstant.height = self.view.frame.size.height
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notifications.decreaseHeightNotification.name, object: nil)
        self.topViewConstraint.constant = -self.view.frame.height / 6
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    } else if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notifications.increaseHeightNotification.name, object: nil)
        self.topViewConstraint.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

Cell.Swift

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(decreaseHeight), name: Notification.Name("decreaseHeightNotification"), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(increaseHeight), name: Notification.Name("increaseHeightNotification"), object: nil)

    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    heightConstraint.constant = (myConstant.height / 3) - 10
    widthConstraint.constant = heightConstraint.constant * 1.5
}

@objc func decreaseHeight() {
    heightConstraint.constant = (myConstant.height / 6) - 10
    widthConstraint.constant = (heightConstraint.constant * 1.5)
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}

@objc func increaseHeight() {
    heightConstraint.constant = (myConstant.height / 3) - 10
    widthConstraint.constant = (heightConstraint.constant * 1.5)
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Now when I scroll both simultaneously, the screen freezes. Also is there a better way of resizing the collectionViewCell size?

Comment: Can you post your code snippet here? This question is incomplete without the approach you are using. Once that is available, you can expect relevant answers.

Comment: @nothingwhatsoever check it out

Comment: Why you are increasing height of your content view ?. it should be leading, trailing , top , bottom with cell so it will automatically increase height as per cell.  after scroll on tableview instead of posting notification use collection view invalidate for this see this http://aplus.rs/2015/how-to-invalidate-flow-collection-view-layout-on-rotation/  .What are you doing in  your height for item at Indexpath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tested it but you can do this. Use Autolayout in this view. it will work better with that.

Set the tableview constraint as Top, Left, Bottom, Right => 0, 0, 0, 0 with the main view and put collectionView under the tableview with constraint as Top,Left,Right, height => 0, 0, 0, x with the main view.

> Note: Tableview is on top of the collectionView.

Connect your height constraint outlet  of CollectionView and also define your defaultOffset variable

```
@IBOutlet weak var defaultHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint
var defaultOffSet: CGPoint?
```

In viewDidLoad,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(collectionView.size.height, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

In viewDidAppear, write

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    defaultOffSet = tableView.contentOffset
}
```

In ViewDidScroll

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = tableView.contentOffset

    if let startOffset = self.defaultOffSet {
        if offset.y < startOffset.y {
            // Scrolling down
            // check if your collection view height is less than normal height, do your logic.


            let deltaY = fabs((startOffset.y - offset.y))
            defaultHeightConstraint.constant = defaultHeightConstraint.constant - deltaY

        } else {
            // Scrolling up
            let deltaY = fabs((startOffset.y - offset.y))
            defaultHeightConstraint.constant = defaultHeightConstraint.constant + deltaY
        }

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, your table view's `delegate` can receive `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods.
You don't need to use PanGesture

First implement `UITableviewDelegate` and in that

```
  var oldContentOffset = CGPoint.zero

  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let contentOffset =  scrollView.contentOffset.y - oldContentOffset.y

    if (self.oldContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
    // moved to top

    } else if (self.oldContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        // moved to bottom
    } else {
        // didn't move
    }
        oldContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
   }
```

Here you can write you logic to change constant value of your constraint

**UPDATE/EDIT**

Another thing is don't use multiplier for tabelview height.with collection view it is fine you can give height constraint with self.view in ratio of 1/3 . for tableview just give leading ,trailing top (UICollectionView) and bottom.
So when you change height constant of UICollectionView Tableview height automatically decrease and vice-versa for decrease.

You can not change the multiplier from the outlet as it is read only. so you have to constant value to `self.view.frame.height  / 3` will work for you

Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: So according to you, for collectionView: use multiplier with 1:3 value. 
For tableView: add top, bottom, left and right constraints. top being relative to collection view.

On scroll: change only multiplier value so everything adjusts automatically?

Comment: @AryanSharma yes !! , You just have to change height of collection view . since tableview top == collectionview.bottom  so tableview automatically adjust as per collection view height changes !! . And you can not change *multiplier value* you have to change **constat** value :)

Answer (score 0):

For a much cleaner approach, why don't you use a `UIScrollView` as the container view and add the `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` inside it and give the `collectionView` a height constraint while disabling `tableView`'s scroll till the height constraint of your `collectionView` becomes 0.

Here's the snippet:

Extend your VC with `UIScrollViewDelegate` and use:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.y <= yourLimit {
            heightConstraint.constant = collectionViewHeight - scrollView.contentOffset.y
            tableView.isScrollEnabled = false

        } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y > yourLimit {
            heightConstraint.constant = collectionViewHeight
            tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

Try this snippet after customizing small things in it. It should work mostly, if it doesn't there is another approach which I'd share once this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add Custom Table Cell with your collection view inside, and when indexPath.row == 0 , return your custom table cell.